# SQL Developer 18 prompting user for variable doesn't work

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle18c

I'm using SQL Developer 18 and I can't get the prompt to work.

The following code works on a virtual machine with a earlier version (version 4.1.4) but does not ask me for a input when I do it on my comp with version 20.4.1

```
select count(*)
from emp
where job = '&job'
group by job;
```

any suggestions?

Comment: You may need to explicitly `set define on;`

Comment: It works. Got the prompt. Thanks

Comment: Look under Preferences->Database and see if you have a connection startup script; that could be changing that to off (and other things). Or a script you ran manually earlier in the session might have turned it off.

Answer (score 0):

```
SET SCAN ON
```

Here it is in version 20.4 (latest)

It prompts me for the value and then replaces the text (not the same as a BIND!) and then runs the query.

[image]

Comment: Hasn't `set scan` been obsolete [for a long time](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/apc.htm)? Is that still preferred over `set define` for SQL Developer?

Comment: what's the difference between set scan on et set define on?

Comment: @AlexPoole  SCAN is easier to type and fewer characters...i doubt it will ever be removed - note this is the default behavior, the OP at some point probably turned this off (it may have been in a script and overlooked)